# Why I cannot center my nav bar?

Tags: html, css

```
h1{
       text-align:center;
       font-family: 'Nosifer', cursive;
       font-size:35px;

    }



    nav { 
        border-top: 5px solid black;
        padding:5px 5px;
                text-align:center;


         }

    nav a:link,a:visited { 
        border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px; 
        padding:0px 15px;
    }


    nav a {

        float: left;
        font-weight: bold;
        color: #000;
        margin: 0 5px; 
        background-color: #131313; 
        font-family: 'Nosifer', cursive;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size: 20px;
        color:red;

        }

    nav a:hover {

        background-color: #D10000; 
        color: black;
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;


        }


        .active{


            background-color: #D10000; 
            color: black;
            padding-top: 12px;
            padding-bottom: 10px;  


        }

        body{
            background-color: #ffe6e6;
        }


  <nav>
     <a href="#" class="active">HOME</a>
     <a href="#">COMPUTER PARTS</a>
     <a href="#">BUILD A COMPUTER</a>
     <a href="#">MEDIA</a>
     <a href="#">GO TO MAIN</a>
  </nav>
```

Can anyone please help me. I tried to use align="center", text-align:center;
and I tried many other things but for some reason, it's not centering my nav bar in the center of my web page. Also when I tried to display an image at the bottom of the nav bar and center it, it does not center.

Comment: what element are you trying to center?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without seeing your markup, it's hard to say. But probably because of `float: left` on `nav a`. Remove that from `nav a`, and add `display: inline-block;`.

Comment: @MiguelWightman awesome you're welcome. Be sure to upvote the answer if it helped and accept it (the check mark by the answer) if you feel it resolved your issue so that other people know it's been resolved

Comment: @MiguelWightman not sure if you've noticed but people are still answering your question because you haven't accepted an answer. Be sure to accept an answer if it's resolved so that people don't think it's open and come and keep giving you solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You're not even positioning anything...

Use the properties `top: value`, `left: value`, `right: value`, and `bottom: value` to position your navigation bar. You can use these properties in combination with `transform: translate(X, Y)`.

`text-align` will only align **text** within an element, if there is indeed text. If there isn't any text, it won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need remove 'float: left' from 'nav a' selector and re-write code following way:

```
nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0 5px; 
    background-color: #131313; 
    font-family: 'Nosifer', cursive;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    color:red;

}
```